# Rails: If views are 'dumb', from where do I tell my database that a piece of content has been viewed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, view

I am putting together an e-learning module in Rails which keeps track of a user's progress. I'd like progress to be updated as content is viewed and for each piece of content to have an index id that corresponds to the index of the progress Array that gets updated.

I have figured out (thanks to stackoverflow) how to serialize an Array as a String to be stored on the database, and I have the Array initializing correctly; It's updating the progress that I don't really know how to implement. I'm kind of new to Rails and don't really know where code should sit.

Do I need to make a Model for each piece of content? What is the best way of communicating to the database that a piece of content (ie a  link) has been clicked? Should that happen in my views?

If anyone has some pointers, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done on the controllers dealing up these pieces of content. You can assume a link to this piece of content has been clicked when the controller action executes. Grab the current user and add this piece of content to your seen_pages array (or whatever it is called). I'm assuming your storing the content seen on your User class under seen_pages_list. This example also assumes you autoload @your_class in the controller. Example:

```
class YourClassController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @current_user.seen_page! @your_class.id

    #rest of your controller logic
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def seen_page!(page_id)
    seen_pages_list.add page_id
    save
  end
end
```

You could make this smarter and not do a save if its not a new page view, why waste the queries right? But as Hoare's Dictum states: 'Premature optmization is the root of all evil'

Comment: I am storing the seen pages on User, yes. So are you saying I DO need 1 controller per clickable-content? Or is there a way to use 1 ContentClass and instantiate it with the appropriate id? If so, I don't think I understand where the Class would be created. (I'm having trouble seeing where Rails actually instantiates anything actually). Or (cue stupid question) is there something else I'm not getting?

Comment: I'm saying, whatever controller is currently serving up these pieces of content should be doing the setting your seen_pages. Now I'm not sure how you're serving up the content but lets just say you have a model named Page, you might also have a controller named PageController with the route pages/:page_id since its a normal resource. Lets say you show a piece of content with the route pages/1/ that goes to your PageController#show, you'd do the work in there.

Comment: OK, thanks. How to I determine which controller is serving up the content? I'm sorry if that's a stupid question, but I just don't know. For example, I have a page that links to /presentation (link_to /presentation). Which controller would that use?

Comment: `rake routes` on the command line and check where /presentation goes. It will tell you a controller and an action.